# How do I share a bigquery dataset with another project?

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I share a bigquery table/dataset with another project?  I do not see an option to share with a specific project.

Comment: what is the exact goal of this? there are a couple ways of doing this depending on your scenario

Comment: I have a big query dataset in project #1 I would like to grant access to that dataset in project #2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't share a dataset with a project. You can share a dataset with a user, a group, or a view, and you can also make a dataset completely public.

If you'd like to share with the users who have access to another project, the best solution is probably to create a Google group (http://groups.google.com), share your dataset with that group, and add that group to project #2. Then you can use membership in the group to control access to both the dataset and the other project.

Once you've shared data with another project, members of that project will probably want to select "Project menu > Switch to project > Display project..." and enter the ID of the other project in order to display those datasets in the web UI's navigation bar.

And since I mentioned it, if you share with a view, you will give access to any user who can query the view, regardless of whether they can access the underlying data.

Comment: I've tried this.  1. I created a new google group 2. Added new members to the google group 3. Gave project #2 permissions to the group 4. Shared data from project # with the group. When access project #2 members of the project do not see data shared with project #2.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From your description, that sounds reasonable. Where are you expecting to see the results? Users trying to view data from another project might need to use "Project menu > Switch to project > Display project..." to view datasets from another project in the web UI. You might also need to wait a little bit for group changes to propagate.

Comment: I was expecting them to show up on project #2.  If they have to switch to project #1 would billing somehow go to project #2?

Comment: The project that actually contains the data will get billed for storage. The project that runs the queries (regardless of where the data is stored) will get billed for the queries.

Comment: For members of project 2, "Switch to project > Display project".. only shows project 2.  Even though data is shared from project 1 with project 2 members of project 2 never see it.

Comment: "Switch to project > Display Project" and then typing in the project name seems to be the key.  thanks

Comment: Hi@Ryan, did you also give permission to project #1 to the group? For me, I could not do "Display Project" to display project 1